# Why does Ingress fail when LoadBalancer works on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check

I can't get Ingress to work on GKE, owing to health check failures. I've tried all of the debugging steps I can think of, including:

- Verified I'm not running low on any quotas
- Verified that my service is accessible from within the cluster
- Verified that my service works behind a k8s/GKE Load Balancer.
- Verified that `healthz` checks are passing in Stackdriver logs

**... I'd love any advice about how to debug or fix. Details below!**

---

I have set up a service with type `LoadBalancer` on GKE. Works great via external IP:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver
  namespace: es
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: echoserver
```

Then I try setting up an Ingress on top of this same service:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echoserver-ingress
  namespace: es
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "echoserver-global-ip"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: echoserver
    servicePort: 80
```

The Ingress gets created, but it thinks the backend nodes are unhealthy:

```
$ kubectl --namespace es describe ingress echoserver-ingress | grep backends
  backends:     {"k8s-be-31102--<snipped>":"UNHEALTHY"}
```

Inspecting the state of the Ingress backend in the GKE web console, I see the same thing:

[image: 0 of 3 healthy]

The health check details appear as expected:

[image: health check details]

... and from within a pod in my cluster I can call the service successfully:

```
# curl  -vvv echoserver  2>&1 | grep "< HTTP"
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK

# curl  -vvv echoserver/healthz  2>&1 | grep "< HTTP"
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

And I can address the service by NodePort:

```
# curl  -vvv 10.0.1.1:31102  2>&1 | grep "< HTTP" 
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

(Which goes without saying, because the Load Balancer service I set up in step 1 resulted in a web site that's working just fine.)

I also see `healthz` checks passing in Stackdriver logs:

[image]

Regarding quotas, I check and see I'm only using 3 of 30 backend services:

```
$ gcloud compute project-info describe | grep -A 1 -B 1  BACKEND_SERVICES
- limit: 30.0
  metric: BACKEND_SERVICES
  usage: 3.0
```

Comment: no idea if this can cause your problem, but at least in the ingress you posted here is a typo, in the "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" annotation "kubernetes" ends with an "n" instead "s"

Comment: Thanks for the close read — just a typo in my post (I updated to fix the typo; the problem persists).

Comment: Did your Ingress deployment create the required firewall rules for HTTP(S) Load Balancer/health checker? Visit [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#firewall_rules) for details of the firewall rules.

Comment: Yes, firewall rules were created automatically under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue a few weeks ago. What fixed it for me was to add a NodePort in the service description so that the Google Cloud Loadbalancer can probe this NodePort. The config that worked for me:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: some-service
spec: 
  selector: 
    name: some-app
  type: NodePort
  ports: 
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32000
      protocol: TCP
```

It might take some time for the ingress to pick this up. You ca re-create the ingress to speed things up.

Comment: Using service `type: LoadBalancer` implies `type: NodePort` ("NodePort and ClusterIP services, to which the external load balancer will route, are automatically created." per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer and I showed this in my logs above).

Comment: Good point @Bosh I read over that but than I am confused why you create a LoadBalancer type and an Ingress controller. The LoadBalancer should give you an external ip already but maybe you got an use-case for this like SSL. Did you try swapping the LoadBalancer type out with a NodePort type just to rule things out?

Comment: I started with a NodePort and saw the same behavior;  I switched to a LoadBalancer so I could document the service working on the internet (and show how it worked through the LoadBalancer and not through the Ingress).

Comment: Thanks, @VincentH. you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the timeout value to be 1 second. Perhaps increasing it to 5 seconds will solve the issue.

Comment: The service responds to requests within a few ms. I don't see how a 1s timeout could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and eventually came across https://stackoverflow.com/a/50645953/9276, which made me look at my firewall settings. Sure enough, the last several NodePort services I had added were not enabled in the firewall rule, and therefore the health checks from the ingress pointing at them all failed. Manually adding the new host ports to the firewall rule fixed this issue for me.

However, unlike the linked answer, I do not have an invalid certificate in use. I'm guessing there are other errors or weird states that can cause this behavior, but I have not found the reason the rules stopped being automatically managed yet.

Possibly unrelated, I did not have this problem in our qa environment, just production, so there may be GCP project level settings at play.